# How to properly handle exception in constructor of disposable object

Tags: c#, exception, dispose, finalizer

Let's say I have this object without unmanaged resources and I don't need or want to use finalizers:

```cs
public sealed class SealedDisposableClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _readLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _writeLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        _readLock.Dispose();
        _writeLock.Dispose();

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Now let's assume hypothetical situation that SemaphoreSlim's constructor can sometimes throw an exception. And let's assume that when we create a new instance of SealedDisposableClass, compiler decides to initialize fields in this order:

```
_readLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
_writeLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

Now let's assume first line executes successfully and we get a managed object _readLock reference stored in _readLock member. And let's assume that second line fails with exception. So we don't get _writeLock reference. And we don't even get SealedDisposableClass instance. Everything just throws on construction. Yet somewhere in the memory there is one SemaphoreSlim instance created.

How to properly handle this situation? Should I always do try/catches in the constructor? Should I add try/catch for SemaphoreSlim's even (or maybe it's always safe to create SemaphoreSlim objects?). Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: If no one is holding a reference to the SemaphoreSlim it will just be garbage collected.

Comment: So GC will call Dispose on it after some time and I don't need to handle this, right? Thanks!

Comment: It is an *extremely* serious mishap.  The only way to make it worse is to try to handle it.  Never ever do that.

Answer (score -1):

You could handle this with a try/catch in the constructor. If you check for the existence of the internal objects before you dispose of them then you could use the dispose-method for cleanup.

```cs
public sealed class SealedDisposableClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _readLock;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _writeLock;
    private bool _isDisposed = false;

    public SealedDisposableClass()
    {
        try
        {
            _readLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
            _writeLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        _readLock?.Dispose();
        _writeLock?.Dispose();

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could do a two step construction where you first instantiate the object and then initialize it before actual usage. This is quite common some places though I find it less user-friendly.

```cs
public void Initialize()
{
    _readLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    _writeLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
}

...

using(var x = new SealedDisposableClass())
{
    x.Initialize();
}
```